# check the async pipe data in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I managed to build a form that can search and bring back results as you type in text.

I mostly used pipe, observables, map in Angular 6. Here is my code

In my service

```
  searchName(name:string):Observable<SearchResult[]>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization',this.token);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/laptops/search?name='+name, {headers:headers})
    .pipe(
      .map(res => {
          return res.json().data.map(item => {
            return new SearchResult(
                item.id,
                item.name
            );
          });
        })
    );
  }
```

and in my component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.results = this.searchField.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(400)
      ,distinctUntilChanged()            
      ,tap( () => console.log('value ', this.searchField.value))
      ,switchMap( a => this.mapcmsService.searchName(a))
      ,tap( () => this.loading = false)
    )
  }
```

So this works, but I want to control the flow of data. I want to kind of intercept the data data to :

check if there are no results in order to show a message. Since I am directly piping the results in the `this.results` , I guess there is no way to suddenly do an `if` . But how can I check for empty results? I can have my node server, that I control to return something like `res.json({success:true, data:false, msg:'no results'});`

check if there is no value in the text input of the form. Again I see no `if` option here and I dont want to hit the db if there is no value.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Use an `*ngIf` within the template

Comment: check if there is no result: `*ngIf="results.length === 0"` in your template. Avoid sending a request to the backend if the input is empty:  `filter(v -> v.length > 0)`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the info. But, I get `Module parse failed: Unexpected token` when I insert the filter. Where I should attach it in the component?

Comment: filter is an observable operator. It should go with the rest of the operators (after distinctUntilChanged()).

Comment: @JBNizet I put `,distinctUntilChanged(), filter(v -> v.length > 0) ...` and I also have `import { filter } from "rxjs/operators";` but still I get `Module parse failed: Unexpected token` about the line  `,distinctUntilChanged()`. The `v` in the filter is the input value that enters the pipe, right?

Comment: Sorry, too much Java: The arrow should of course be a fat arrow: `v => v.length > 0`. Yes v is the value emitted by the valueChanges observable.

Comment: @JBNizet Ah, I should see it too, but since I am an angular newbie I thought that is the right angular syntax. It works now, thanks. Fee free to turn your comments to an answer, so I can upvote and choose as the accepted one.